# EclipseLink EntityManager SQL JOIN on two tables

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have 2 different tables: `subjects` and `questions` and I need to make SQL JOIN on these 2 tables. Table `subjects` has its attributes: `name` and `shortcut`. Table `questions` has its attributes: `question_number`, `text`, `subject` - in fact, `subject` from table `questions` is a `shortcut` of a `subject`.

I tried something like this, what I saw in one stackoverflow topic:

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT q.question_number, q.text, s.name, s.shortcut FROM "
                                   + "( questions q INNER JOIN subjects s ON q.subject=s.shortcut );", QuestionSubject.class);
```

`QuestionSubject.class` is an `@Entity` class and has attributes of both `questions` table and `subjects` table. After calling this method I saw that a new table with a name `QUESTIONSUBJECT` was created in my database and that is what I do not want to be done.

Can anyone help me with other solution?

P.S.: I am doing this in order to use the ouput as a response on HTTP request so I need to gather those two into one. I need to return either a `List` or `JSON` string.

EDIT: Using MySQL database.

`questions` table Entity class:

```
package model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@Entity
@Table(name = "questions")
@XmlRootElement
public class Question implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Basic(optional = false)
   @Column(name = "question_number")
    private Integer questionNumber;
   @Column(name = "text")
    private String text;
   @Column(name = "subject")
    private String subject;

    public Question() {
    }

    public Question(Integer questionNumber) {
        this.questionNumber = questionNumber;
    }

    public Question( String text, String subject) {
        this.text = text;
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public Question(Integer questionNumber, String text, String subject) {
        this.questionNumber = questionNumber;
        this.text = text;
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public Integer getQuestionNumber() {
        return questionNumber;
    }

    public void setQuestionNumber(Integer questionNumber) {
        this.questionNumber = questionNumber;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (questionNumber != null ? questionNumber.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Question)) {
            return false;
        }
        Question other = (Question) object;
        if ((this.questionNumber == null && other.questionNumber != null) || (this.questionNumber != null && !this.questionNumber.equals(other.questionNumber))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Rest.Questions[ questionNumber=" + questionNumber + " ]";
    }

}
```

`subjects` table Entity class.

```
package model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Lob;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@Entity
@Table(name = "subjects")
@XmlRootElement
public class Subject implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
   @Basic(optional = false)
   @NotNull
   @Size(min = 1, max = 5)
   @Column(name = "shortcut")
    private String shortcut;
    @Basic(optional = false)
   @NotNull
   @Lob
   @Size(min = 1, max = 65535)
   @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    public Subject() {
    }

    public Subject(String shortcut) {
        this.shortcut = shortcut;
    }

    public Subject(String shortcut, String name) {
        this.shortcut = shortcut;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getShortcut() {
        return shortcut;
    }

    public void setShortcut(String shortcut) {
        this.shortcut = shortcut;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (shortcut != null ? shortcut.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Subject)) {
            return false;
        }
        Subject other = (Subject) object;
        if ((this.shortcut == null && other.shortcut != null) || (this.shortcut != null && !this.shortcut.equals(other.shortcut))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Rest.Subjects[ shortcut=" + shortcut + " ]";
    }

}
```

`QuestionSubject` Entity class:

```
package model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class QuestionSubject implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "question_number")
    private Integer questionNumber;
    @Column(name = "text")
    private String text;

    @Column(name = "shortcut")
    private String shortcut;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    public Integer getQuestionNumber() {
        return questionNumber;
    }

    public void setQuestionNumber(Integer questionNumber) {
        this.questionNumber = questionNumber;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getShortcut() {
        return shortcut;
    }

    public void setShortcut(String shortcut) {
        this.shortcut = shortcut;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: I never used EclipseLink as JPA provider (and I don't know which database is behind) but I guess the tables are not created on query time. Usually the mappings (class definitions) define the table structure and the tables are created on startup. Can you please post code of the related classes?

Comment: This command created a new table on query time. Sure, I will upload it in 2 mins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table gets created because you define a class named `QuestionSubject` annotated as `@Entity`. Per default the table name is the class name.

You could override the name like you did in `Subjects` with `@Table(name = "subjects")`

Nearly the same would happen if you would define a `@ManyToMany` mapping on related fields between classes `Question` and `Subject` without defining `QuestionSubject` class at all.

I would recommend to take a look here to get more information:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Mapping/Relationship_Mappings/Collection_Mappings/ManyToMany

**Edit**
If you need a manyToMany mapping you need this table. Otherwise you can only have an oneToMany resp. manyToOne relation (using foreign keys).

Comment: In fact, is it true that when I create a relation many to many in SQL, then a new table is created that represents this fact?

Comment: Sure, how should the manyToMany relation otherwise be persisted? It's called 'join table', 'mapping table' or similar.